# Syntax error on "x", VariableDeclaratorld expected after this

Tags: java, class, object, processing

```
class anyName
{
  int Tcol = 0;
  int fc = 0;
  int x = 0;
  float randx = (random(1, 1000));
  float randy = (random (0, 600));
  int Tsizes = 1;
  {
    if (fc >= x) { //Random Ellipse 3
      stroke (Tcol);
      fill (Tcol);
      ellipse (randx, randy, Tsizes, Tsizes);
    }
  }
}

anyName ranx1 = new anyName();
ranx1.x = 100;
```

Hi, I am trying to add a class/object to my code and it is not working. This is the class I have so far, but when I instantiate one object from that class (ranx1), and then try change one of the variables inside it (x), it says there is a error. Is there anything I need to change? I would really appreciate any help.

Since I instantiated an object from that class, how would I change the variables for the new object? For example, if in the class x = 0, then I made a copy and this time I want x to = 100, but all the other variables such as Tcol and fc to stay the same. I know this is possible because my teacher taught it, but it is not working right now for me.

```
ranx1.x = 100;
```

Comment: When do you think that the `if`is being executed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variables as "public" if you are trying to access from a class that is not in the same package.

Comment: Technically right, but this an anti-advice to newbies - should never have a public class variable in real-world code!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is you are trying to access to that attribute from a class that is in another package, you should declare the atrributes as public to gain access to them. But this solution wouldn't be totally correct, a better approach is declaring them as private and creating public getters and setters to access/modify them.

Said that, you should post a working example, that piece code does not compile because you are trying to execute code that is out of any class... and I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the curly braces before the `if` clause.

Comment: Can you please give me your email? I would like to email you about this please, I need help because it is not working.

Comment: You can ask here, SO is the right place to make questions

Answer (score 0):

when you careate a class, every member has a control access.

when you don't state the control access like:

```
public x;
protected fc;
private Tcol;
```

they all get default private.

you can't access private members from outside the class.

do:

```
class anyName
{
  public int Tcol = 0;
  public int fc = 0;
  public int x = 0;
  public float randx = (random(1, 1000));
  public float randy = (random (0, 600));
  public int Tsizes = 1;
  {
    if (fc >= x) { //Random Ellipse 3
      stroke (Tcol);
      fill (Tcol);
      ellipse (randx, randy, Tsizes, Tsizes);
    }
  }
}
```

whoever, i must point out that most times it's not recommended to set members access as public and you should learn about getter and setters.

now i hope the rest of your code is in a main function and in a main class, but if not it should be like so:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[]args){
      anyName ranx1 = new anyName();
      ranx1.x = 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's wrong, there is a default access which is not private, protected or public. Actually is pretty close to the protected one.

Comment: what? the default is private for members!

Comment: No, there is  a package-private level, where the members are accesible within the same package but not for children classes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot access sub class veriables like that. If you want to access you should make this

```
 public class ExampleApp {  
    class anyName
    {
      int x = 0;     
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        ExampleApp ea = new ExampleApp();
        ExampleApp.anyName ranx1= ea.new anyName();
        ranx1.x =100;
    }
  }
```

Or you can use them inside of the class with method

```
    public void method() {
    anyName ea = new anyName();
    ea.x=100;

}
```

you cannot use your veriables private if you want to access them.Secondly if you want to use this libraries you cant use innerclass. Inside of innerclass you cannot access libraries because java sees it in diffrent package. If you make it public class and import Math you can use it otherwise you should make method for your ellipse, random .